# Excel formula: determine budget

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a budget for the next 10 years for a number of items. Every item has his own expected life time in years.

example:

Smartphone 3years €500.
I want to create a spreadsheet from 2022 untill 2031 where for every item in each year there will be a value if in that year the item should be replaced.

is this possible?

Comment: So divide the time period by the item lifetime and roundup to the next integer. Multiply by the cost. Add to get the total.

Comment: It is possible to create an Excel file, containing some data and doing some basic calculations on it. However, if you want those data to come from some exotic source and you want some extremely special calculations and handling to be done, it might prove difficult. Please edit your question, showing what you are trying to do, what you want to achieve and what are the problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your spreadsheet looks like this (date and year are excel dates).

| Item | Expire Date | Cost |  | Year | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell | 9/27/2024 | £500 |  | 2021 | £0 |
| Socks | 9/28/2022 | £20 |  | 2022 | £20 |
| Hat | 9/27/2024 | £50 |  | 2023 | £0 |
|  |  |  |  | 2024 | £550 |

Your formula in cell `F2` is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$4,--(YEAR($B$2:$B$4)=YEAR(E5)))
```

As a dynamic array, you could put this into cell `E2`.

```
=LET(
    Years, YEAR(B2:B4),
    Costs, C2:C4,

    ListYears, SORT(UNIQUE(Years)),
    tYears, TRANSPOSE(Years),
    tCosts, TRANSPOSE(Costs),

    MaskArray, --tYears=ListYears,
    CostArray, MaskArray*tCosts,
    OnesArray, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Years),,1,0),
    Totals, MMULT(CostArray,{1;1;1}),

    CHOOSE({1,2},ListYears,Totals)
)
```